# Where is the question I just posted?

Tags: support, questions, posting

How long does it take for a posted question to become available?  I posted a question about 30 minutes ago and I can't find it.

The title is "Android Client won't bind to Service".

Comment: Are you sure it actually posted? What do you see when you click on "Ask Question" on SO?

Comment: There is no time-out. It should appear immediately. Are you sure you posted it? Has it been deleted perhaps? (Perhaps there still is a link in your browser history?)

Comment: I don't see any recently created questions of yours. they appear instantly of your profile page. it's also not deleted /cc @bart

Comment: I guess I'll try it again.  Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it happens almost immediately.  This is probably not the problem you are seeing.

Comment: the tiny version of your profile pic on mobile looks like something... different than it is ;) There's no problem with it; just making a humorous observation.

Comment: Huh.  I think I'm going to sit over here in a corner for a little while and try to unsee that.

Answer (score 5):

The question should appear pretty much immediately.

If you don't see it in any of the question lists, you can find it listed in your own question list on [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2584082/user2584082).

It seems you don't have any (non-deleted) posts with that title. Are you sure you actually posted the question, and didn't get any kind of error when submitting it?

Comment: Immediately ~= a few seconds, it takes a bit longer